# String to date conversion in R

Tags: r, date

Here is a simple example to reproduce the problem I am facing.

```
>d<-"1/24/2014"
>x<-as.Date(d,"%m/%d/%y")
>x
[1] "2020-01-24"
```

Now, where is 2020 coming from?

Comment: `as.Date(d,"%m/%d/%Y")` `%y` is for two-digit years

Comment: Please study the documentation. `%y` denotes the short year format (e.g., `14`).

Comment: Try `%Y` instead of `%y`. More info on `?strptime`

Comment: It's not a duplicate of 14276160!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to combine everything said above, using %y is telling R to only read the first two digits of the year, which is why 2020 is the year in your output.